# How to fill NaN values in a pandas dataframe, with variable values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
   Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
2  NaN      NaN      AGTCTA   AGT
5  NaN      GC       NaN      NaN
```

And want to replace the NaN values in the Isolate1 column with dashes, one dash for each letter in the non NaN values from the other columns (or the maximum number if other column has other different value), ending in something like these:

```
  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
2 ------   NaN      AGTCTA   AGT
5 --       GC       NaN      NaN
```

I have tried the following:

```
index_sizes_to_replace = {}
for row in df.itertuples():
    indel_sizes = []
    #0 pos is index
    for i, value in enumerate(row[1:]):
        if pd.notnull(value):
            indel_sizes.append((i, len(value)))
    max_size = max([size for i, size in indel_sizes])
    index_sizes_to_replace[row[0]]= max_size
```

Now I have the number of dashes to replace the NaN values, but dont know how to do the filling, tried this:

```
for index, size in index_sizes_to_replace.iteritems():
    df.iloc[index].fillna("-"*size, inplace=True)
```

But didnt work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = dict(Isolate1=[np.NaN,np.NaN,'A'],
            Isolate2=[np.NaN,'ABC','A'],
            Isolate3=['AGT',np.NaN,'A'],
            Isolate4=['AGTCTA',np.NaN,'A'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Original solution:

```
df['Isolate1'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-' * x.str.len().max().astype(int), axis=1)
```

To ignore Isolate1:

```
df['Isolate1'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.str.len().max().astype(int)*'-', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
0   ------      NaN      AGT   AGTCTA
1      ---      ABC      NaN      NaN
2        -        A        A        A
```

---

@Anton vBR Edit to handle not nan in col1.

```
# Create a mask
m = pd.isna(df['Isolate1'])
df.loc[m,'Isolate1'] = df[m].apply(lambda x: '-' * x.str.len().max().astype(int), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
0   ------      NaN      AGT   AGTCTA
1      ---      ABC      NaN      NaN
2        A        A        A        A
```

Comment: this is a nice one ! :)

Comment: I think this answer fits OP's needs better!

Comment: @AntonvBR, thanks for the warning, fortunately that case doesnt happen

Comment: @ScottBoston, but what happens if the isolate1 column does not have a NaN value? would it be replaced to dashes accordingly to the length of the values of other columns, right? Can the apply only be made to NaN values?

Comment: @AntonvBR dont know what you mean by that, the loc would be before the apply or to apply it to a df filtered on the rows with NaN in the isolate1 column?

Comment: @RafaelRios I'm going to look at it soon. First I am looking at why the script crashes.

Comment: @RafaelRios currently the script looks at all columns it doesn't ignore the Isolate1, however you can use .iloc[:,1:] to only apply the lambda to all other columns then replace Isolate1.

Comment: @AntonvBR, modified the function to include the name of the column, rather than its position, adding it as a parameter to make it more general, thank you very much

Comment: @RafaelRios But do you see now what I mean with loc? It really is more compact and easier to understand. ANyway.. see you guys around!

Comment: @AntonvBR, yeah it is more readable in case I only need to modify the first column, but if the column I need to change is not the first one, I needed another approach.

Answer (score 6):

It looks bit ugly, but it does the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = dict(Isolate1=[np.NaN,np.NaN],
            Isolate2=[np.NaN,'GC'],
            Isolate3=['AGTCTA',np.NaN],
            Isolate4=['AGT',np.NaN])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Isolate1'] = (df.drop('Isolate1',1).ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
                         .iloc[:,0].replace('.', '-', regex=True))

print(df)
```

Returns

```
  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
2   ------      NaN   AGTCTA      AGT
5       --       GC      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: @Anton vBR, thank you for editing! Don't you use `pd.read_clipboard()` ?

Comment: I do, but I like to fix the data sometimes. :)

Comment: Wow, can you explain a little bit for the replace('.', '-', regex=True) part ?

Comment: no, it does the trick, the maximum vlue was just my approximation to do it as didnt know how to count the number of dashes

Comment: If I understood, the drop removes the column, the ffill and bfill are the fillnan, propagated from the front or back across the column, and the iloc goes for each value of each column?

Comment: @RafaelRios, yep :)

Comment: @AntonvBR, no it would be 6 dashes, ideally the number of dashes would be equal to the longest size of the non NaN value

Comment: @Wen, Max, I've come up with something different, what do you two think?

Answer (score 4):

**Setup**

```
df

  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
0      NaN      NaN      AGT   AGTCTA
1      NaN      ABC      NaN      NaN
2        A        A        A        A
```

**Solution**
Using `fillna` + `apply` + `str.__mul__`:

```
df['Isolate1'] = df.Isolate1.fillna(
       df.fillna('').applymap(len).max(1).apply('-'.__mul__)
)

  Isolate1 Isolate2 Isolate3 Isolate4
0   ------      NaN      AGT   AGTCTA
1      ---      ABC      NaN      NaN
2        A        A        A        A
```

Comment: Nice dude :-)  !

Comment: The fillna with empty strings is necessary to avoid errors due to the type of NaN, right?